# Swift/IOS Reset ImageView zoom in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following hierarchy:
UIViewController -> UICollectionView -> UICollectionViewCell -> UIScrollView -> UIImageView -> UIImage

With this hierarchy, I can have working-well zooming capability. But when I am done zooming-in, and swipe in to the next image, I need the previous imageview to reset to its original scale.

My Attempt:
I stored the current index in my collection into

```
self.currendIndex
```

and then tried getting the collection view cell and set its scrollview zooming like so in the scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating event inside the view controller

```
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.currendIndex, section: 0)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.scrollView.zoomScale = 1
            cell.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't zoom it down, it just goes to the next element and then when I come back it is still with the zoom level.

How to fix it?

Comment: Try without the `async`.

Comment: @sunkehappy thank you for ur comment, but it still didn't work with removing that async

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the reloadItems method:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.currendIndex, section: 0)

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    })
}
```

and it had to be inside the async